# Creating own map and using it in offline WPF Application?

Tags: .net, software-recommendations, wpf, offline

I need to create my parcel's map, I got high resolution photo from the sky and i want to georeference it and add few features like routes and buildings. Then I need to use it in WPF applicion where I would click on the buildnig and dispaly information about them, also trace a route.

This application has to be offline, so can you recommend any App to create a map and compatible API for .NET?

I'm newbie in GIS.